# Get first and last value from range in a spreadsheet using other column's data for filter criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, macros, worksheet-function

I have data in my spreadsheet in a worksheet like this:

[image: 1]

Where the data goes in this format

[ID] | [Date] | [Hour] |

And I have another worksheet where I want the data to be like this:

[image: 2]

Where I want the data displayed to be like:

[DateRange's First ID + " - " + DateRange's Last ID] | [DateRange's First ID + " - " + DateRange's Last ID] | [Date]

How could I make this using formulas or VBA macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using PivotTable a bit...

I would run a PivotTable onto the data, put `Date` as row labels, and two `ID` in Values. The first ID will be summarized by minimum, and the second by maximum.

[image]

Then, you can Copy/Paste (Paste values and format the date) the information you need into a new sheet, where you will move the date column to the right. Insert two columns between the Max ID and the Date, then do a simple concatenate:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2," - ",B2)
```

(I forgot the spaces in my screenshot below)

[image]

This formula also works: `=A2&" - "&B2`

You only need to rename the column headings and after removing the formulae in the cells through Copy/Paste Values, you can delete columns A and B.

Comment: @JhonAlx You're welcome :)

Comment: Just have to do some copy/pasting but it saves me a whole lotta time :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first and last ID, try

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(C1,Sheet1!B:B,0))&" - "&INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(C1,Sheet1!B:B,1))
```

where C1 on the current sheet has the date.

If the IDs are not in ascending order and you want the lowest ID and the highest ID for the date, try

```
=MIN(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(C1,Sheet1!B:B,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(C1,Sheet1!B:B,1)))&" - "&MAX(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(C1,Sheet1!B:B,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(C1,Sheet1!B:B,1)))
```

Comment: +1 because it works but @Jerry solution is faster :)